# PHP cron job does not execute only if I manually execute via cli

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I have a cron job set up to write a local json file. It should run every hour and over write 
previous file. but it is not running unless I run it manually via the cli. Here is how i have set up on the crontab

```
00 * * * * php /var/www/cron_jobs/pixel_mapping.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

the permissions of the php file are

```
rw-rw-r--  1  username username  822 Apr 13 11:02 pixel_mapping.php
```

my user permissions are

```
drwxrwxr-x
```

If I run it as php /var/www/cron_jobs/pixel_mapping.php on the cli 
it does write to the json file. any ideas or trouble shooting ideas to try and 
have this done by the cron?
many thanks

Comment: Who is the CRON running as, same user? Log what happens. Change `>/dev/null 2>&1` to `>> /var/log/..../whatsmycrondoing.log`

Comment: @user3783243 yes cron is running as same user. ok, ill try loggin

Comment: Redirecting logs to dev null in a cron job is probably not a good idea, however the cron task itself has logs which may state what the problem is https://serverfault.com/a/136464

Comment: Probably `/usr/bin/php` or wherever it is.

Comment: okay so I checked the /var/syslog and there is no record of the cron task